# Compare result query of AJAX request to know the data is updated or not?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I plan to use AJAX for updating my page every 2 seconds, so the content of page always refreshes every 2 seconds although the data that it requests the same the old one. So I want to compare them if data the same, it should not refresh the content. And I have searched to find solution and idea to implement it also and some ideas say that if we compare an object collection it can be slow.
So the question is how or what technique to compare it with acceptance performance during the query collection has 50 to 70 objects?
Or you have any idea to suggest...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by generating [MD5 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) for the content. If two strings are same, the hash will always be generated the same.

So, you can generate an MD5 hash for the response, and return it as part of your response (store it somewhere locally on the browser). After some time, your AJAX call will fire, and if the response is the same, the hash will again be the same. Compare both the hashes and decide if you want to replace the content or not.

Hashes can be compared easily as they are mere strings. Hope this adds a bit of solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the [Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) for this kind of thing. You can probably send a broadcast message after relevant data has been updated in your database.
Otherwise, the MD5 hash technique as described by @31piy is also a good approach, but it won't be scalable for future needs in case you decide to Ramp up your Project